# Json object grouping

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to format my json in a good format as the following:

```
+---+----------+---------------------------------+
|   | John doe | heading:John doe already exist  |
|   |          | info:id 1 already already exist |
|   |          |                                 |
|   |          |                                 |
| 1 |          | heading: xxx                    |
|   |          | info: xxxxxxxxxxxx              |
|   |          |                                 |
|   |          | heading: 123                    |
|   |          | info: xxxxxxxxxxxx              |
+---+----------+---------------------------------+
```

Here is my json object

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "request": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "John doe"
            },
            "success": false,
            "errors": [
                {
                    "heading": "name",
                    "info": "John doe already exist"
                },
                {
                    "heading": "id",
                    "info": "id 1 already already exist"
                },
                {
                    "heading": "xx",
                    "info": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                },
                 {
                    "heading": "123",
                    "info": "xxxxvvvvvxxxxxxxxx"
                }
            ],
            "message": "Insert failed"
        }]

}
```

I have tried the following (below) but it will only return a single **heading and info** while it should return multiple *errors*

```
  var dataR= json.data.filter(item => !item.success).map(function (c) {
       return {
               heading: c.errors[0].heading,
               info: c.errors[0].info
              }})
```

Comment: `heading: c.errors.map(({heading}) => heading).join('. ')` - and same for `info`

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: what to you mean formatting? Do you want to show data in html? or create a pattern as shown in your question?

Comment: Maybe make it clear to yourself what `json.data.filter(item => !item.success)` returns in the first place? I don’t think what you are calling `.map()` on here, is what you actually wanted to map … Or you are still missing one level of actual “looping” over data.

Comment: @CBroe  json.data.filter(item => !item.success) returns    {
                    {"heading": "name","info": "John doe already exist"}

Comment: @Jaromanda X .. almost there! but i'm getting>>>>  heading: "[object Object]. [object Object]"
Info: "[object Object]. [object Object]"

Comment: _“json.data.filter(item => !item.success) returns { {"heading": "name","info": "John doe already exist"}”_ … not it doesn’t, at least not if `json` is supposed to be the complete structure you have shown …? It returns `[{"request":{"id":1,"name":"John doe"},"success":false,"errors":[{"heading":"name","info":"John doe already exist"},{"heading":"id","info":"id 1 already already exist"},{"heading":"xx","info":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx"},{"heading":"123","info":"xxxxvvvvvxxxxxxxxx"}],"message":"Insert failed"}]`

Comment: Perhaps you read my code wrong - did you do `({heading}) => heading` or did you decide that looked funny and do `(heading) => heading` instead? because the code I presented will NOT produce the result you claim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will join the headings and infos as one string, each one separated by `". "` - use some other sequence if you wish in the `.join`

```js
const json = {
  "data": [{
    "request": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "John doe"
    },
    "success": false,
    "errors": [{
      "heading": "name",
      "info": "John doe already exist"
    }, {
      "heading": "id",
      "info": "id 1 already already exist"
    }, {
      "heading": "xx",
      "info": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }, {
      "heading": "123",
      "info": "xxxxvvvvvxxxxxxxxx"
    }],
    "message": "Insert failed"
  }]
};
var dataR = json.data.filter(item => !item.success).map(function(c) {
  return {
    heading: c.errors.map(({heading}) => heading).join('. '),
    info: c.errors.map(({info}) => info).join('. ')
  }
})
console.log(dataR);
```

per comment that `({heading}) => heading` doesn't work

try

```
return {
    heading: c.errors.map(error => error.heading).join('. '),
    info: c.errors.map(error => error.info).join('. ')
}
```

Comment: great solution! {heading} and {info} isn't running on my current javascript version because of the curly braces

Comment: oh ... what are you using? internet explorer? no, wait, you're using `=>` so ... what javscript are you using?

Comment: added a workaround for that bizarre version of javascript you are using :p

Comment: many thanks for the updates, using your solution, i was able to learn something new today and resolve my issue.. thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

May be you can do something like that.

```
 json.data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item.request.id] = acc[item.request.id] || {};
   acc[item.request.id].name = item.request.name;
acc[item.request.id].errors = item.errors;
return acc;
}, {})
```

Comment: @JaromandaX, he needs to format the data and I am just giving the right direction within current scope :)

Comment: your resultant object does not result in an object like `{
               heading: "all the headings,
               info: "all the infos"
              }`